# Slicing list inside a method (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.4, slice

I have a method like the following:

```
def slice_list(my_list, slice_point):
    my_list = my_list[:slice_point]
    print("Inside method: ", my_list)

    return
```

I have a test for it like the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    slice_point = 3

    slice_list(my_list, slice_point)
    print("Outside method: ", my_list)
```

The output I get is not what I expected for, in the sense that the list is not ultimately edited

```
>>>Inside method:  [1, 2, 3]
>>>Outside method:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But when I do an `append` to the list, it does edit the list for good, as this example shows:

```
def append_to_list(my_list, element):
    my_list.append(element)
    print("Inside method: ", my_list)

    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    append_to_list(my_list, "new element")
    print("Outside method: ", my_list)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
>>>Inside method:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'new element']
>>>Outside method:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'new element']
```

**Why does the slice not change the list for good?**

Comment: You should read about local and global variables. Unless specified as global, any variable that is created or reassigned in a function is considered local. But append does not reassign...

Comment: Also, you're function is not a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
my_list[:] = my_list[:slice_point]
```

Your old method just points the name `my_list` at a new object, i.e. at the copy returned by the slice.

The suggestion I've proposed above, however, modifies the object which `my_list` originally pointed at without rebinding that name.